Guardar Huella en base de datos Firebird con Ibexpert
tengo una situación, estoy tratando de guardar una huella digital leida a través de un digital personal 4500, pero no sé como guardar la huella para posterior compararla con una nueva lectura de huella, estuve leyendo y dicen que debes guardar este dato en un VARBINARY(MAX) sin embargo en IbexPert no encuentro esta opción ¿cuál sería su equivalente en este editor de base de datos?. Gracias
